# Drainage options for house on flat lot?

Tags: drains

I have a home on a relatively flat lot. I want to be very aggressive in removing moisture and am looking for ideas/suggestions.

My current thoughts:
1. Re-grade
2. Add a swale - again not sure my lawn can support this well, but I am also thinking about lowering the soil right up against my fence, then draining that out somehow.

Any thoughts, or other options?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve or prevent? It looks like a new house, is there an existing issue? Where specifically are you (so we can at least guess at typical precipitation)?

Comment: 1950's but recently remodeled. The issue is a lot of interior movement + drywall cracks. Northern California.

Answer (score 1):

At least it's level on all sides. Worst case is when banks slope TOWARD the house. I've dealt with them, as well as the level drainage issues.

So here's what I did on one area that was problematic. The soil was rich, black and clay. I built up the clay as high as possible along much of the outside wall, sloping it toward the yard. It worked well.

In my current house, here in Georgia, I have fought water coming down from a field into the garden area. The soil is Georgia's finest red clay. After a good storm, water saturates the top soil and stays soggy for weeks. I dug a trench along the inside of my fence and laid down two 4" perf plastic drain pipe that I'd run through a sock to keep loose dirt from clogging the holes. I filled the hole with gravel just over the pipe, and the rest of the way with top soil. It catches the water and drains it down to the creek. It's a modification of a French drain.

Try banking soil up against your house, sloping toward the yard. If still a concern, try trenching around your house and putting in a drain.

Water's always going to fight back. Persistence is the key to success.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if that type of drain you installed require much ongoing maintenance? Like, do those socks get mossy and clogged?